# How can do Split on RDD of Row type in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file `json` on HDFS, I read it:

```
var data = sqlContext.read.json("/.....")
```

This following, it's Schema:

```
 |-- @timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- beat: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hostname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- env: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- env2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- env3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- format: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- version: double (nullable = true)
 |-- input_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

I want do a split of the field `text`, I tried by:

```
var myRDD = data.select("text").rdd

var split_myRDD = myRDD.map(ligne => ligne.split("|"))
```

It does not work:  error: value split is not a member of `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Someone can tell me where's the fault ?

Comment: `myRDD` is of type `RDD[Row]`. while applying `.split()` you need to get the actual value from `Row`. Use `var split_myRDD = myRDD.map(ligne => ligne.getAs[String](0).split("|"))`

Comment: It's worked, but it display just two fields: value and inside field element ?
I don't find all the rest of the fields.

Comment: What do you mean by rest of the fields?

Comment: it display :

root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)  when I do printSchema

Comment: yes, but what do you need?, the splitted values along with remaining columns from original json input?

Comment: myRDD.map(row => row.getAs[String]("text").split("|"))

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to RDD for that. You can use split function in DF. The code will look like this.

```
df.select("text")
  .withColumn("text_split", split(col("text"), "\\|"))
```

You can also use RDD if there is some special need and use "\\|" to split the text. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you read your JSON, the resulted object is a DataFrame. When you convert a Dataframe to an RDD, you will have an array of [Row]. A Row Class describe a Row from your Dataframe, and have the same schema as your DataFrame. To be able to take an element from a Row you should do this:

```
myRDD
  .map(row => row.getString(row.fieldIndex("text")).split("|"))
```